# why is this mesh disappearing?

Tags: mesh

I have this XPS model from a video game and I am just doing my process of converting the outfit for sims 4 studios (and the game)

Problem is, the mesh disappearing? When I first imported the mesh it was fine. [image]

Then, I go ahead and put it with the sims 4 body to combine
and then the mesh becomes like this.
[image]
[image]
[![as seen from above, the mesh was perfectly fine, but now the mesh is transparent? There are no texture problems, polygon problems. This type of error is sooo confusing for me to adjust.]

Comment: This would not have been an issue if you had made this mesh by your self.

Comment: wwow so helpful